# can skew plane exist in a 4-dimensional affine space

Tags: geometry

In my opinion, yes
 if the equations of the plane are:

$$\pi = \begin{cases}AX+BY+CZ+DW+E=0\\A'X+B'Y+C'Z+D'W+E'=0\end{cases}$$
$$\pi' = \begin{cases}A"X+B"Y+C"Z+D"W+E"=0\\A"'X+B"'Y+C"'Z+D"'W+E"'=0\end{cases}$$

and
$$\pi \cap \pi'=\begin{cases}AX+BY+CZ+DW+E=0\\A'X+B'Y+C'Z+D'W+E'=0\\A"X+B"Y+C"Z+D"W+E"=0\\A"'X+B"'Y+C"'Z+D"'W+E"'=0\end{cases}$$

has rank 3  and r(A|b)>r(A)

Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but instead of writing out the fully general equations, it is perhaps more instructive to see a concrete example:

Consider $\pi_1$ defined by $\{x=0,w=1\}$ and $\pi_2$ defined by $\{y=0,w=2\}$. Clearly the planes don't intersect, but they are not parallel either, since displacements *in* the planes span the $xyz$-space together.

Comment: Thanks for your help